# How does one choose permissions for each folder?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, directory

I understand how to change the permissions on my folders using CHMOD and CHOWN but I'm not sure what the permissions should be.  For example, the first folder currently gives full access to root, read and execute to group root and for some reason executable access to everyone.  That doesn't seem to make sense to me.  I keep thinking I'm not reading it correctly but it could also be necessary for some unknown reason.

Note, I have my permissions for var/www/html (where I am putting my website) as 755, but these are the other directories and they seem to be leaving things open to random people.  I'm mainly concerned that if I shut them all off, some web functionalities won't work.

```
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jul 24 06:35 backups
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root   4096 Jul 23 20:54 cache
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Apr 20 06:23 crash
drwxr-xr-x 34 root root   4096 Jul 23 20:54 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff  4096 Apr 10 15:12 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Apr 20 06:20 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 11 root syslog 4096 Jul 24 06:35 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail   4096 Apr 16 14:02 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 16 14:02 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Apr 20 06:20 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Apr 20 06:20 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Apr 20 06:24 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Jul 23 14:19 www
```

Comment: I leave mine the way ubuntu has them to prevent issues.

Answer (score 2):

The execute bit means "can make that directory current" and has nothing to do with being able to execute files in that directory

Check out [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened) for a much more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions are in set of three characters.
drwxr-xr-x. d, indicates its an directory. Now set of 3, this says all permissions to file/directory owner.next set, read and executable permission to group. Last set, read and executable to others.

Permission are from 0 to 7
0 no-permission
1 executable-x
2 write-w
3 -wx
4 read-r
5 r-x
6 rw-
7 rwx

There are some set of prototypes we have to follow while working with permissions.
1.) If you are giving write permission, read is mandatory.
2.) Do not give executable permission to the files.

3.) File permission max is 666. Directory 777

You were asking you didn't get why root and other having access to your file.
That is because of umask command.
umask is inverse of chmod. chmod is used to give permission, umask is used to revoke permission.

When ever user create a file or folder it gives full access to all users. Like 777
by default umask is set to 022. It will revoke, no permission for file owner, write permission from group and others. So permission is now 755.

And don't try to delete those file. /var directory is the most important directory. It contains all of your application based programs, Cache file, temporary file, and queue files.